# SJF Algorithm (SRTFS) - Calculate Sorting the Processes?

Tags: algorithm, sorting

[image]
Ok, I have the table above, and I need to calculate the average waiting time using the preemptive SJF algorithm, but to do that, you must first 'sort' these processes, which I think I don't understand properly how to do.

If I knew how to sort them, I'd have no trouble calculating the average waiting time at all.

Here's what I came up with, but I think it's probably wrong.

My Probably Wrong Solution:
[image]

Comment: If you're going to use obscure acronyms, ***please*** provide a link that explains what you are talking about.

Answer (score 0):

Sorting requires an ordering/comparison operation like >=. It's shocking that you are using an algorithm with its own acronym (and what is SRTFS??) before learning how to sort. However once you know what it is you want to sort, you can use one of the java.util.Arrays.sort() methods.

Comment: Sorry Sir, but your reply is completely out of context. This has nothing to do with arrays or Java programming or C Programming or any programming at all.

I found out that what I wanted was called the Gantt Chart for the Preemptive SJF Algorithm a.k.a. the SRTFS Algorithm.

On a second note, I think my solution was correct.